# PhpSpreadsheet set background color of cell to white

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Using PhpSpreadsheet, I want to set a white background to the excel cell.

```
$cells = 'A1';
$spreadsheet
    ->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle($cells)
    ->getFill()
    ->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)
    ->getStartColor(' #FFFFFF')
    ->setARGB('#FFFFFF');
```

This code makes the cell background black even if I set this white RGB color value: `#FFFFFF`.

The result I would like to achieve:

[image: BEFORE]

[image: AFTER]

Comment: Can anyone show me what is wrong with this code..                                          '$sheet->getStyle('A1:E3')->applyFromArray(array(
      'fill' => array(
          'type' => Fill::FILL_SOLID,
          'color' => array('rgb' => 'E5E4E2' )
      ));'

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You don't have to include the `#` symbol when you specify the ARGB for PhpSpreadsheet. These solutions will be able to set the cell background to white:

### Cell by cell

```
$spreadsheet
    ->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle($cells)
    ->getFill()
    ->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)
    ->getStartColor()
    ->setARGB('ffffff');
```

### Range of cells

```
$spreadsheet
    ->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A1:A5')
    ->getFill()
    ->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)
    ->getStartColor()
    ->setARGB('ffffff');
```

Answer (score 12):

By using a style array to set few styles at once:

```
styleArray = array(
            'borders' => array(
                'outline' => array(
                    'borderStyle' => Border::BORDER_THICK,
                    'color' => array('argb' => '00000000'),
                ),
            ),
            'fill' => array(
                'fillType' => Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                'startColor' => array('argb' => 'FF4F81BD')
            )
        );
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->applyFromArray($styleArray);
```

In some examples, we find 'fill' instead of 'fillType'. Perhaps it depends on version of phpSpreadsheet. Another variant is 'color' instead of 'startColor'.

Comment: There seems to be a getStyle() missing in the last line.
For me it's always been:

$spreadtsheet->getActiveSheet->getStyle($cellOrRange)->applyFromArray($styleArray);